# Execute php script from within wordpress hosted on hostgator

Tags: php, wordpress

so i have a scheduling algorithm written in php it consists of around 15 files. 
i now want to move this scheduler to my personal website which is built using wordpress and host gator. This is the final goal.

My question, how do i exicute a simple helloworld php script when the button is pressed

I have a wordpress page which has a button that when pressed i want to run a php script, helloworld.php -aledsworld.com/button1

but when pressed it goes to this address - aledsworld.com/button1/helloworld.php which gives page not found

i can upload the php script to the server because this works - aledsworld.com/helloworld.php even though i loose all the css

So my question is where is the folder that i need to upload helloworld.php too?

Answer (score 0):

Your script needs to execute the php script. You can do this using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), etc.

```
if (isset($_POST['button_press'])) {
    exec('php helloworld.php');
}
```

Host Gator may not allow you to use exec though...